# android listview update one row from edittext in alertdialog

Tags: android, listview, android-alertdialog

I have a custom array list. My listview will look like that ;

```
   1 | How old are you? | (Answer- textview3)
   2 | what is your name ? | (Answer- textview3)
```

When I click on item an alertdialog will open. User will enter his age and press next button. After that my listview item should be refreshed and look like this;

```
  1 | How old are you? | 35
  2 | what is your name ? | (Answer)
```

I can access to textview3 and set the user input. But user input just shows a second after that listview looks like before, I mean listview item doesnt change. I tried to use adapter.notifyDatasetChanged but it does not work.